# installed perl module cannot be accessed by normal user on fedora 23

Tags: perl, module, fedora

After root installed module Net::SFTP::Foreign on fedora 23, the normal user cannot access it though he can cd to there, but list is empty of /usr/local/share/perl5.

```
[root@PES-CMCC-DB ~]# !find
find `perl -e "print \"@INC\";"` -name "Foreign.pm"
/usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm
./.cpan/build/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.81-TYvkdG/blib/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm
./.cpan/build/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.81-TYvkdG/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm

[root@PES-CMCC-DB perl5]# pwd
/usr/local/share/perl5
[root@PES-CMCC-DB perl5]# ls
Algorithm  CPAN   Expect.pm  JSON       Module  ok.pm  Perl    Spiffy.pm   TAP   Time     YAML.pod
App        Crypt  File       LEOCHARRE  Net     Parse  Smart   Spiffy.pod  Test  YAML
CAM        Devel  Getopt     Linux      Number  PDF    Spiffy  String      Text  YAML.pm

[pes@NP-CTC-DB ~]$ perl testDwdUnzip.pl 
Can't locate Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SFTP::Foreign module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at testDwdUnzip.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at testDwdUnzip.pl line 2.
[pes@NP-CTC-DB ~]$ find `perl -e "print \"@INC\";"` -name "Foreign.pm"
[pes@NP-CTC-DB ~]$ 

[pes@NP-CTC-DB perl5]$ pwd
/usr/local/share/perl5
[pes@NP-CTC-DB perl5]$ ls -l
total 0
[pes@NP-CTC-DB perl5]$
```

I want to know, if fedora introduced some special access-control method.

Comment: [pes@NP-CTC-DB ~]$ perl testDwdUnzip.pl 
Can't locate Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SFTP::Foreign module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at testDwdUnzip.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at testDwdUnzip.pl line 2.
[pes@NP-CTC-DB ~]$

Comment: How did you install the module as root, and what does `@INC` contain when you run _testDwdUnzip.pl_ as the user?

Comment: Are you running on the same machine in both cases? Your prompt as root shows `root@PES-CMCC-DB`, compared to `pes@NP-CTC-DB` as the regular user. Running `ls -l /usr/local/share/perl5` should show either the same files for both users, or give a permission denied error for the regular user.

Comment: thanks ThisSuitlsBlackNot for your words. yes, I have mess these two hosts. Now, I have installed this module on host NP-CTC-DB, it can work